# calculation to show image on website every 3rd week

Tags: javascript, java, grails

I have a grails project where need to show on call team icon on home page. there are three images for three team. teams rotate every 3 week so for example team 1 logo will show first (1)and last week(4) of month and so one..
I have tried putting in db table for all 52 weeks and team no and putting it in session-

code in service-

```
    sql.query("SELECT * FROM tbl_ImageForTeamUser where weekno=?",[wkno]) 
    { rs ->             
        while (rs.next()) {
            def userinf = new UserInfo()
            userinf.weekno= rs.getInt("weekno")
            userinf.teamname= rs.getString("teamname")
            userinf.teamno= rs.getInt("teamno")
            items.add(userinf)
        }
      }
```

Saved in session-

```
session.weekno= items[0].teamno()
```

UI looks like-

```
<tr>
            <g:if test="${session.weekno == "1" }">
                 <td class="team1" align="right"  nowrap></br></br></td>
             </g:if>
            <g:if test="${session.weekno == "2"}">
                <td class="team2" align="right"  nowrap></br></br></td>
            </g:if>
            <g:if test="${session.weekno == "3" }">
                 <td class="team3" align="right"  nowrap></br></br></td>
             </g:if>
```

but somehow this is not looking a good solution. please suggest a better ,coding suggestion .dont want to use DB and handle it on UI side.

Comment: This isn't a forum. If you have a *specific* problem that can be answered *specifically* so that it will be helpful to others with the same *specific* problem, then it belongs here on stack overflow. Your question is too general.

Comment: First, *try* making something out of those specifications. Then, if you run into a specific problem along the way, such as "The timer is activating every week instead of every 3rd week. I've tried to fix this by doing --insertsomecode--, but it's not working. Where am I going wrong?", then you can post that here.

Comment: sorry guys.I should have added what i did . I have tried DB way and make changes to my original post for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH) will give you 1 2 3 4 5 or the the week of the month it is.

You can use this to print the correct order without having to store it in a database table. because you only have 3 unique ordering of the pictures if I understand your question correctly.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
def weekOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)
def teamImageCountShown = weekOfMonth % 3
if(teamImageCountShown==1){
    //Display 1 2 3
}
if(teamImageCountShown==2){
    //Display 2 3 1
}
if(teamImageCountShown==0){
    //Display 3 1 2
}
```

Comment: thanks . Neoryder. I have done this in very similar as your solution. made 3 java array for each team and got week using same as yours -Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) .checked and show picture. thanks.